# php_intl.dll 4+ in xamp 1.7.4 + php 5.3.5 V6 for symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, xampp, icu

I'm trying to setup symfony under my local development machine using xampp 1.7.4 (with PHP 5.3.5 V6) but I'm getting this warning:

> Upgrade your intl extension with a newer ICU version (4+).

I've tried downloading the source from windows.php.net but the version there is only for PHP VC9 (for PHP 5.3)

I've also downloaded the latest version of ICU in http://site.icu-project.org/download but I'm missing the curresponding dll.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Under windows you need at least PHP **5.3.8** to get ICU version 4+. You only have 5.3.5. Check if there is an update for PHP with XAMPP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [the PHP PECL intl extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/intl)

[Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) is another windows AMP stack, the last version comes with php 5.3.8...

Good luck

Comment: Did you see that thread on the symfony forum ? [link](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=35747)

Comment: sorry for the delay. I decided to drop out the symfony 2 'cause the production server does not meet the minimum requirements yet. For now we are working with 1.4 version. I'll look at that problem in a couple of months probably. Thanks!!

Comment: Never mind ... But Symfony 2 is very different from version 1.4... On occasion, have a look on Wamp, it is easily accessible and has a large community